# Renci.SshNet 2016.0.0.0 throwing file not found System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.0.0.0

Tags: c#, windows, console-application, ssh.net

I am trying to use the latest Renci.SshNet 2016.0.0.0 in one of my C# projects with the intent start autosys job from C#. When I try to create an object of SshClient, I am getting the below exception:

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

I downloaded System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms 4.0.0-beta-23516 and referenced it in the project, but still getting the same exception. Here is the line where the exception is thrown.

```
SshClient client = new SshClient(server, userName, password);
```

Console application created in Visual Studio 2013 targeting .Net Framework 4.6.

Looking forward to suggestions.

Comment: Do you have it at least added to the using in the class header as well as added manually to the references-> Node..?

Comment: @MethodMan: Yes, they are added in the class with Using statement and also in the References

Comment: try changing your target to 4.0 and seeing if it works then